# Comparing strings in an if: !string.equals("") vs !"".equals(string)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between these two conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084049/difference-between-these-two-conditions)

I am doing some code cleanup and NetBeans made a suggestion to change

`if(!billAddress1.equals(""))` to `if (!"".equals(billAddress1))`.

What is the difference between the two, and the advantages of using the suggested version over the readability of the original version?

Comment: See this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084049/difference-between-these-two-conditions/13084072#13084072

Comment: Add this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888508/string-equals-argument-ordering

Comment: Well it seems I have a resounding answer to this question :) Thanks everyone, answer will be accepted once min time is up.

Comment: so many `equally` right answers ;))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`billAddress1.equals("")` will cause a NullPointerException if `billAddress1` is `null`, `"".equals(billAddress1)` wont.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Could cause a NullPointerException if billAddress1 is null
if(!billAddress1.equals(""))

// Will not cause a NullPointerException if billAddress1 is null
if (!"".equals(billAddress1))
```

Answer (score 3):

`!"".equals(billAddress1)` will never cause an `NPE`, so it allows a more compact syntax by allowing to get rid of the `billAddress1 == null` that would otherwise be required.

Answer (score 2):

The latter will not cause a Null pointer exception if the value is null.

Answer (score 2):

One saves you from NPE as others have pointed out. But if you are sure it's not going to be null then the better way to check if a string is empty is to use the [`String.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) method, that's what the code seems to be trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The first one has a potential to cause NullPointerException.